# Finding Percentile from Data set and eliminating outliers

Tags: excel

Disclaimer, I am completely new to excel coding VBA etc and I am having a tough time even figuring out what I have to do.

In short, I have lengthy amount of raw data, and I need to determine the 95th and 5th percentile for each day (i.e. 14/3/2017), and subsequently remove rows with the values above/below the 95th and 5th percentile. It is tedious to find the percentile value for each day and use the or function to remove the outliers. I appreciate all help and please understand that I am very new to this hence I may not understand what you reply or where to put any code.
Thank you for all help

Comment: can you please share what you have done to solve your problem?

Comment: Does "Select data > Home > Conditional formatting > highlight top 5% " do what you need?